# Why addition operation is not defined in a series for infinite term and addition operation of infinite terms are not defined?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Why addition operation is not defined in a series for infinite  term and addition operation of infinite terms are not defined? Are there any way to define it for infinite term?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Unsure what you are asking.  Does this represent what you are interested in: given the infinite sequence $~a_1, a_2, \cdots , ~$ let $~L = a_1 + a_2 + \cdots = \displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n a_k = \sum_{k=1}^\infty a_k.$